# Multivariate Normal Distribution Diagonal Covariance Matrix

Tags: probability-distributions, notation, normal-distribution

I am reading through a paper and they have a multivariate distribution with the second parameter (covariance matrix as follows)

[image: MVN(m, SI)]

I know its hard to determine without context but what does this imply (covariance matrix = sI) ? None of the variables are related?

Comment: Yes... the second term in the normal is the covariance matrix, here some scalar $s^0$ times the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This means "multivariate normal" with (vector) mean ${\bf m}^0$ and covariance scalar $s^0$ times the identity matrix, ${\bf I}$.